# Different visuals show different results for the same measure (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, mapbox, calculation, measure, choropleth

I added the same measure in the Mapbox visual and in the table, but the calculation results are different. In Mapbox, some of the values ​​are correct, and some are not. Why does this happen?
For an example: table shows numbers set 2, 61, 9 and Mapbox Choropleth legend shows 2, 32, 61 at same time

My measure (if it is important):

```
Value = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Filter'[Filter by]),
    "NFI Kits", CALCULATE(COUNT(data[NFI Kits])),
    "WASH Kits", CALCULATE(COUNT(data[WASH Kits])),
    "Beneficiaries", CALCULATE(SUM(Data[Number of household members]), FILTER('Data', 'Data'[Amount of aid received]>0)))
```